# How to filter packets with distinct source address in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, sorting, packet, pcap

I have a `pcap` file and I want to `wireshark` shows me packets with distinct source address. How can I do this in `wireshark`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the IPv4 tab in the Endpoints (or Conversations) item under the Statistics menu to see a list of unique hosts (or conversations). You can further filter your capture from here too by right-clicking on a specific entry.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried this before, But in the Endpoints, there isn't any packet to show.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment to EMK's answer, it seems what you're looking for is a unique list of source IP addresses in a capture file.  Assuming so, you can achieve this with [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) as follows:

On *nix platforms:

```
tshark -r capture.pcap -T fields -e ip.src | sort -u
```

On Windows, you will probably need a batch file to accomplish equivalent of `sort -u`.  You can probably use the one provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841024/using-windows-dos-shell-batch-commands-how-do-i-take-a-file-and-only-keep-uniqu), and provided below:

```
tshark.exe -r capture.pcap -T fields -e ip.src > uniqinput.txt
sortuniq.bat uniqinput.txt
```

Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "prev="
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('sort uniqinput.txt') do (
  set "curr=%%F"
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  if "!prev!" neq "!curr!" echo !curr!
  endlocal
  set "prev=%%F"
)
```

Comment: Where is the output of this?: 'tshark -r capture.pcap -T fields -e ip.src | sort -u'

Comment: The output goes to `stdout` by default; you can redirect it to a file or pipe it to another command if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for the IPV4 source, e.g.

```
ip.src == 192.168.0.200
```

**Tip**: In the Packet View, you can right click a value and choose "Apply as filter".

Comment: No, suppose that we have 10 packets, and 4 of these have ip.src == 192.168.1.100, 4 of others have ip,src == 192.168.1.101 and remainder have ip.src == 192.168.1.102. Now I want to wireshark shows me just three packets with ip.src == 192.168.1.100, 192.168.1.101 and 192.168.1.102.